# Store data on page to variables using Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am trying to store data to variables on the page when a button is clicked, there are multiple buttons and it needs to store data for that specific button.  Each one of these buttons is nested inside a `<form onsubmit></form>` all the data I need to extra is within this form in different `<input>` and `<div>` tags.  So using javascript or jquery how can I select the value of a specific  and  tag.  So when the button is clicked on it adds this product to the cart, I want to take the productNumber, price, and quantity and store them to my own variables.  When the button is clicked the forum calls onsubmit="ShoppingCartAddAJAX( this ); so I want to store this data in the ShoppingCartAddAJAX function.

Here is what one of the forms on the page looks like.

```
<form method="post" name="addtocart-501" onsubmit="ShoppingCartAddAJAX( this ); return false;">
    <input type="hidden" name="formName" value="ShoppingCartAddAJAX" />
    <input type="hidden" name="productNumber" value="758201" />
    <input id="qtyproduct" type="hidden" class="hiddenqty" name="dmst_Qty_2805" value="1" />
                    <div class="price">  
                        <div class="pricenew singleprice">
                            $7.99
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</form>
```

So I have been trying to get this data by doing something like this.

```
var pn = $('input[name$="productNumber"]').val();
var qty = $('input[id$="qtyproduct"]').val();
```

In my javascript file the function looks something like this:

```
function ShoppingCartAddAJAX(formElement, productNumber) {

var pn = $('formElement.input[name$="productNumber"]').val();
var aa = $('formElement[name$="productNumber"]').val();
var qty = $('input[id$="qtyproduct"]').val();
}
```

But with alot more code... just showing that the function is passing in formElement and a productNumber.

But this is giving me the product number and quantity of the first product on the page, I need the data for which ever button the user decides to click on and there are multiple ones on the page not just one.  I hope that when the button is clicked and that function is fired there is a way to look what forum it came from and then extract that data.  I would also like to be able to get the price but it is stored in `<div class="pricenew singleprice"> $7.99</div>`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey! `alt` is not a valid `a` attribute! (So I've removed it while formatting your HTML indentation)

Comment: According to your onsumbmit attribute(in the form), your function can accept only one parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the product number and quantity of the first record since you have multiple input fields in the form with the name of `productNumber`(according to your description). So what basically happens here is when you call `$('input[name="productNumber"]').val()` jquery returns you the value of the first input field. Instead of that, do something like this inside your `ShoppingCartAddAJAX` function.

```
function ShoppingCartAddAJAX(form)
{
    // Find child an element inside our form with the id of "qtyproduct"
    // I used "find("#qtyproduct")" method so it searches anything nested inside your specific form element
    // You can use "children("#qtyproduct")" method also

    var qty = $(form).find("#qtyproduct").val();
    var pn  = $(form).find("input[name='productNumber']").val();
    var pp  = $(form).find(".pricenew.singleprice").text();
}
```

Comment: So for the product number and quantity I got it to work using: 
var pn = $(formElement).find('input[name$="productNumber"]').val();

var qty = $(formElement).find('input[id$="qtyproduct"]').val();

Now how can I select the price out of that div? Btw thanks!

<div class="pricenew singleprice"> $7.99</div>

Comment: My guess would be var pp = $(formElement).find('div.pricenew singleprice');

Comment: I've updated my answer. Try visiting this link to learn more about Jquery selectors. http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: When I use var pp  = $(formElement).find(".pricenew.singleprice").val();
and $(formElement).find(".pricenew.singleprice"); I get this
[prevObject: m.fn.init[8], context: document, jquery: "1.11.1", constructor: function, selector: ""…]